# HttpClient throws error on SendAsync (C#)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, exchangewebservices

My code (C#):

```
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;
        //httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        httpClientHandler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        //httpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usr", "pw", "domain");
        httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var httpcontent = new StringContent(content);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        httpClient.BaseAddress = ews_url;

        // var request = httpClient.PostAsync(ews_url, httpcontent);
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        requestMessage.RequestUri = ews_url;
        requestMessage.Content = httpcontent;
        requestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        var request = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage); 
        HttpResponseMessage response = await request; // --> Error
```

the instance of HttpClient (httpClient) always runs into an exception in the line marked with the --> Error comment. I can not find any wrong code lines. The exception says: "the underlying connection closed", "Error on sending" but the connection is not closed as you see. I tried several options like "UseDefaultCredentials true/false", "new NetworkCredentials".

My scenario is an App sending soap messages to exchange web services (ews).

Do you have any ideas solving my problem?

Comment: does a Fiddler trace shed any light on what's going back and forth on the wire?

Comment: This could be a race condition. Does it work if you use Send instead of SendAsync?

Comment: Fiddler said 401 Unauthorized, but i am authorized as you see in my code.

Comment: There is no "Send", because i am using WinRT.

Comment: Did you use URL with https:// ??

Comment: yes. but configured fiddler to encrypt.

Comment: did you get this figured out?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @TWilly: ich resoved the problem by creating a new IIS Service using EWS Library from M$ the Windows Store App only communicates per new Service with the Exchange Service. (No need of direct SOAP calls)